# How to remove MAUI Blazor White Splash?

Tags: maui-blazor

I am thinking since Maui Blazor is newer technology that there might be a way to remove the white splash that comes in while the app is loading up.

In my index.html file I already have
`<html lang="en" style="background-color:black">`

When I begin debugging my application it starts out black, flashes white for a moment and then goes black again. The white flash doesn't give the app a clean look (like what could be achieved in Maui Xaml), but I have chosen to go with Maui Blazor as UI development will be easier.

I know with a traditional web app that getting rid of the white initial screen would be impossible. But, since we have control of the system (technically) before the web shim even starts up is there a way that we could make the web engine use black instead while it waits to get initial resources?

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice. I've been scouring the web but info is hard to find with Maui being so new.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the `Splash Screen` of the `MAUI Blazor` app, you can try to drag an image with **black** background into the Resources\Splash folder of the project, where its build action will automatically be set to `MauiSplashScreen` like below.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splashscreen.svg" Color="#000000" BaseSize="128,128" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Would this only be for the final built executable? As I still seem to get the white flash even with this implemented when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

We've that covered in BitPlatform [Templates](https://bitplatform.dev/todo-template/getting-started):

Android, iOS and MacCatalyst:
https://github.com/bitfoundation/bitplatform/blob/develop/src/Templates/TodoTemplate/Bit.TodoTemplate/src/Client/App/MainPage.xaml.cs

WinUI:
https://github.com/bitfoundation/bitplatform/blob/develop/src/Templates/TodoTemplate/Bit.TodoTemplate/src/Client/App/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml